# Input Signal Out Of Range

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, hardware-detection

I'm gonna start out by saying I'v been baffled by this and there is probably a very simple answer but I can't seem to figure it out.

So I have 2 monitors, 1 Is my **main one / gaming one**, and my other one is my **work one** that used to be a tv

The problem I'm having is when I turn off my second monitor, my main monitor will go black and display

> Input Signal Out Of Range 1600x900 60 Hz

Then when I turn my second monitor back on and my main one will work again!

WTF!?!?

**Some information**

1. Main Monitor: HP - VGA
2. Second Monitor: Philips TV - HDMI
3. Windows 10
4. Graphics Card: AMD Radeon R9 390x
5. All Drivers Updated

When I go into safe mode I can unplug my second monitor and my first monitor doesn't display the message. There is only one problem Windows thinks that my main monitor is my second one so it displays it at 1280x720 and it 
**ALSO SAYS THAT IT IS THE PHILIPS MONITOR IN THE CONTROL PANEL** 
and I can't change it.

*I will put pictures later, as I'm away from my PC right now.*

Comment: If Windows "thinks my main monitor is my second one" and if you turn it off, the HDMI signal will be lost and the card will try to make your other monitor your main monitor and the settings are too high for that monitor. You need to configure Windows to set your first monitor as the main monitor. In Display Settings, choose that monitor and check the box that says "Make this my main display". Click apply.

Comment: @HighTechGeek My main monitor is set as the Main one in Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

With both monitors connected and powered on, temporarily set the resolution and Hz on BOTH to something low that both monitors can handle.

Also, change it from "extend these displays" to "duplicate these displays"

Then restart.

Both monitors should now be showing the same thing at the same resolution.

Now see if you can set what you want to be the main monitor in Window's Display Settings to "Make this my main display" and then "extend these displays" again.

Restart and then you can increase the resolution on the second monitor.

Comment: When I try to apply "Duplicate These Displays" it says "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings." [Here is a image for reference](http://imgur.com/a/9lVXb)

Comment: Did you try first setting the resolutions low on both and restarting before setting "Duplicate These Displays"? Also try getting a lowest common denominator for the Hz

Comment: yes I did this multiple times.